# Android NSDManager is not working on 4.3 (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android

I am using NSDManager class for discovering services with in the network, in 4.1 and 4.4 i am able to discovering services and in 4.3 application is hanging and crashing after some time. Please let me know if you facing same issue? application is hanging while creating NSDManager instance.

Code:

NsdManager mNsdManager;
mNsdManager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);